# Visits by Traffic Type as a metric

Tags: c#, google-analytics, google-api

I'm writing software to analyse my website traffic.
I've got tomething like that in query:

```
var query1 = new DataQuery(dataFeedUrl)
                {
                    Ids = string.Format("ga:{0}", profileId),
                    Metrics = "ga:visits,ga:newVisits,ga:organicSearches",
                    Sort = "ga:visits",
                    GAStartDate = startDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
                    GAEndDate = endDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
                    StartIndex = 1
                };
```

I have to get more data about Visits by Traffic Type (not only organicSearches), like:

- Direct
- Referral
- Paid
- Mailing

How can I get them as a metric?
Kind regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by adding dimensions to your query related to traffic source. This will enable you to see data for metrics like visits, new visits, etc. but separated out by traffic source.

I don't know C#, but I'd imagine the code would be something like this:

```
var query1 = new DataQuery(dataFeedUrl)
            {
                Ids = string.Format("ga:{0}", profileId),
                Dimensions = "ga:source,ga:medium",
                Metrics = "ga:visits,ga:newVisits",
                Sort = "ga:visits",
                GAStartDate = startDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
                GAEndDate = endDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
                StartIndex = 1
            };
```

Documentation on all of the dimension and metric combinations you can use can be found here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets

You can also experiment with different query parameters using the GA Query Explorer: http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/

Comment: GA Query Explorer is a great tool - I found in it, that ga:medium is exactly that I'm looking for!